# Can I get Travis CI's status as a json response?

Tags: travis-ci

I can get Travis's status at https://www.traviscistatus.com/. I'd like to be able to get the same info in a json object (or at least some sort of structured response). Similar to what I get from: https://status.github.com/api/status.json or https://status.heroku.com/api/v3/current-status. Is there a simple URL that will give me that? I can parse the HTML from traviscistatus.com if I have to, but surely there's a better way?

(I'm having a hard time googling for this since there's so much about how to get a *build* status, which is *not* what I want.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the page is powered by statuspage.io you might be able to use their [API](https://doers.statuspage.io/api/v1/), but it's not immediately obvious to me if you can get an API token that is valid for "foreign" pages. 
Other than that there's the [atom feed](https://www.traviscistatus.com/history.atom) which would be easy to parse, but might not have everything you want.

Comment: I looked into the statuspage API, but had the same confusion you did. Hadn't thought of going the atom route, that's a big improvement over HTML parsing. I'll mark this correct and use history.atom. Thanks!